# Refactor "package structure" in Eclipse to relocate a package's child package to its parent package

Tags: java, eclipse, package, refactoring

In Eclipse's "Package Explorer", let's say I have a list of packages like this:

- com.animal.dog
- com.animal.cat
- com.animal.frog

If I want to refactor this package structure so that the final package structure looks like

- com.dog
- com.cat
- com.frog

So essentially removing the parent package & attaching the child packages to its grandparent. I have many child packages in "com.animal" package & I would like to avoid if possible doing this manually & then also changing the package imports everywhere.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you switch your package representation to `hierarchical` (from arrow on the top-right), you can right-click the `com.animal` package and rename it to `com`.

Comment: I believe you've meant renaming to `com` (not `animal`).

Answer (score 17):

Probably you don't have any classes directly under `com.animal`. What you can do is either follow Bozho's suggestion (and switch to hierarchical view) or create a temporary class directly under `com.animal`. This way Eclipse would present a separate entry for `com.animal`.

Having selected `com.animal` you can simply do the rename refactoring. Make sure you select the 'Rename subpackages' checkbox.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. this would have worked as well but I just switched to Hierarchical view as @Bozho suggested.